# Center flexbox in mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

**Problem:**

A container that has three boxes is positioned in the center in desktop view. However, it is not in the center when viewed on a mobile.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

**HTML**

```
<article>
  <section class="category cars">Cars</section>
  <section class="category food">Food</section>
  <section class="category drinks">Drinks</section>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Layout */
article {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.category {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Background colors */
.cars {
  background-color: crimson;
}
.food {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.drinks {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

/* Mobile view */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  article {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

**Current output:**

The three boxes are positioned to the **left**.

**Desired output:**

The three boxes should center in the **middle** on a mobile view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple.
When you change the direction to `column` the axis gets reversed too. So, adding `align-items: center;` will center the boxes.

This is what you need:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  article {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding a parent element to the `<article>` tag. Then, add `display: flex; width: 100%;justify-content: center;` to the parent element **ONLY IN THE MEDIA QUERY**.

This will make the `<article>` tag come in the center. The parent element has `background: none` which makes it look like the `<article>` container is in the middle

```css
/* Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Layout */
article {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.category {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
/* Background colors */
.cars {
  background-color: crimson;
}
.food {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.drinks {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

/* Mobile view */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  article {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .parent{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <article>
  <section class="category cars">Cars</section>
  <section class="category food">Food</section>
  <section class="category drinks">Drinks</section>
  </article>
</div>
```

**OR**

You could add `align-items: center` to the column because you have set `flex-direction: column` to the `<article>` tag so in this case `align-items` will work like `justify-content`

I hope it helped!

**OR**

You could use relative positioning. Adding `left: 50%;position: relative;transform: translateX(-50%);` to the article in media query will also help **IN SOME CASES**